# Typescript: Call static method inside the class (Angular HttpInterceptor)

Tags: angular, typescript, static, static-methods, angular-http-interceptors

I'm currently working on an http interceptor that worked well until yesterday.

It defines static methods and one of them does not want to be recognized.

The console says:

> my.component.ts:162 Error in PUT Request TypeError: HttpInterceptorService_1.httpInterceptorService.createHttpErrorMessage is not a function

```
at TapSubscriber._tapNext (http-interceptor.service.ts:113)
at TapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/tap.js.TapSubscriber._next (tap.js:45)
at TapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
at TakeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/take.js.TakeSubscriber._next (take.js:40)
at TakeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
at Notification.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Notification.js.Notification.observe (Notification.js:15)
at AsyncAction.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/delay.js.DelaySubscriber.dispatch [as work] (delay.js:42)
at AsyncAction.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/scheduler/AsyncAction.js.AsyncAction._execute (AsyncAction.js:63)
at AsyncAction.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/scheduler/AsyncAction.js.AsyncAction.execute (AsyncAction.js:51)
at AsyncScheduler.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/scheduler/AsyncScheduler.js.AsyncScheduler.flush (AsyncScheduler.js:43)
```

My interceptor looks like this (I have reduced it to the parts that are interesting for the bug):

```
// My imports

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  // Other static stuff and below my httpInterceptorService
  static httpInterceptorService: HttpInterceptorService;

  constructor(
    httpInterceptorService: HttpInterceptorService,
  ) {
    HttpInterceptorService.httpInterceptorService = httpInterceptorService;;
  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      // Some headers
    });

    const clone = req.clone({
      // ..
    });

    return next.handle(clone).pipe(
      // ..
    );
  }

  createHttpErrorMessage(error: HttpErrorResponse, statusText: string) {
    const msg: string = error.status + ' ' + error.statusText + ' - ' + statusText;
    switch (error.status) {
      case 404:
        this.showError('Error ID: ' + this.id, msg);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
    console.error(
      // Some error messages
    );
  }

  handleHttpError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (my condition) {
      // some logic
    } else {
      return throwError(error).pipe(
        retryWhen(errors => errors.pipe(
          delay(1000),
          take(1),
          tap(() => {
            switch (error.status) {
              case 404: // This method is not recognized anymore.. 
                HttpInterceptorService.httpInterceptorService.createHttpErrorMessage(
                  error, HttpInterceptorService.otherService.doSomething());
                break;
              default:
                console.error(error);
                break;
              }
            }),
          ),
        )
      );
    }
  }
}
```

As I said, the Interceptor has worked without any problems so far, until this error appeared yesterday.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The part where I commented "This method is not recognized anymore.."

Comment: Change it to `this.createHttpErrorMessage(...)` OR make the method static and invoke it using `HttpInterceptorService.createHttpErrorMessage(...)`

Comment: ++ Why do you *really* need a static reference in your service class?

Comment: With this.createHttpErrorMessage the console says: _this.createHttpErrorMessage is not a function. It seem to work with making the method static and move it to the top. I also had to make another method static in order to make it work. I had to make it static because a lot of other stuff is going on in that service and it was the only way to make it work :(

Comment: If you want you can post your comment as an answer to let me confirm it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make one of the following changes in order to fix the compilation issues.

- Invoke it using

  ```
  this.createHttpErrorMessage(...)
  ```

OR

- Make the method static and invoke it using

  ```
  HttpInterceptorService.createHttpErrorMessage(...)
  ```